# Store services and activity with periodicity related in each other

Tags: php, mysql, checkbox

HTML

```
<form method='post' id='userform' action='arrayvalue.php'>



       <input type='checkbox' name='servicevar[]' value='Gst'>Gst<br> <br>


        <input type='checkbox' name='activityvar[]' value='Return'>Return<br>
         <input type='checkbox' name='pervar[]' value='Monthly'>Monthly<br>
         <input type='checkbox' name='pervar[]' value='Yearly'>Yearly<br>



        <input type='checkbox' name='activityvar[]' value='Filling'>Filling<br>
          <input type='checkbox' name='pervar[]'value='Monthly'>Monthly<br>
          <input type='checkbox' name='pervar[]' value='Yearly'>Yearly<br>
        <br>




        <input type='checkbox' name='arr[2][service]' value='Incometax'>Incometax<br> <br>


        <input type='checkbox' name='arr[2][activity][]' value='Return'>Return<br>
         <input type='checkbox' name='arr[2][per][]' value='Monthly'>Monthly<br>
         <input type='checkbox' name='arr[2][per][]' value='Yearly'>Yearly<br>



        <input type='checkbox' name='activityvar[]' value='Filling'>Filling<br>
          <input type='checkbox' name='pervar[]'value='Monthly'>Monthly<br>
          <input type='checkbox' name='pervar[]' value='Yearly'>Yearly<br>



        <input type='checkbox' name='activityvar[]' value='Return'>Revised<br>
         <input type='checkbox' name='pervar[]' value='Monthly'>Monthly<br>
         <input type='checkbox' name='pervar[]' value='Yearly'>Yearly<br>
        <br>

   <input type='submit' name="submit" class='buttons'>
</form>
```

The output of this code is:-

- Gst

  - Return

    - Monthly
    - Yearly
  - Filling

    - Monthly
    - Yearly
- Incometax

  - Return

    - Monthly
    - Yearly
  - Filling

    - Monthly
    - Yearly
  - Revised

    - Monthly
    - Yearly

I store all this values in mapping table,

I have serviceactivitymap Table where I store service with related activity,

I have activitypermap Table where I store activity related to periodicity.

```
     foreach ($_POST['arr'] as $input) {


            $servicevalue = $input['service'];
                $query2 = mysql_query("insert into mapclientservice(client_id,service_id)values('$firmid','$servicevalue')",$connection);



          foreach ($input['activity'] as $activity) {

            $servicevalue = $input['service'];

             $query3 = mysql_query("insert into mapserviceactivity(service_id,activity_id)values('$servicess','$activity')",$connection);


             foreach ($input['timeperiod'] as $period) {

                $query4 = mysql_query("insert into mapactivityperodicity(activity_id,perodicity_id)values('$activity','$period')",$connection);

             }

        }

    }
```

This is used for store services activity and periodicity.
But when I store activity and periodicity then there is problem,value of periodicity not store correct.

All the checked periodicity stored with all activity,
How to store it with proper activity with periodicity